# UniversalindentGUI "(STDERR):Cannot find file indentinput.cpp" Error

Tags: c++, formatting, format, universalindentgui

I wanted to know if anyone have used [UniversalindentGUI](http://universalindent.sourceforge.net/).

I am trying to use and when run it get the following error.

There is no proper documentation or tutorial how to use it, if any one have used it please help me.

```
Indenter returned with exit code: 1
Indent console output was: 
(STDOUT):
(STDERR):Cannot find file indentinput.cpp
```

Callstring was:

```
"/Users/rbang/Desktop/Tools/UniversalIndentGUI_macx/indenters/astyle"
indentinput.cpp 
--options="/Users/rbang/Desktop/Tools/UniversalIndentGUI_macx/temp/.astylerc"
```

Answer (score 1):

Open up `indenters/uigui_astyle.ini` in the directory where UniversalIndentGUI is installed and find the following properties:

```
inputFileName=indentinput
inputFileParameter=
outputFileName=indentinput
outputFileParameter=none
```

Change them to:

```
inputFileName=
inputFileParameter=stdin
outputFileName=
outputFileParameter=stdout
```

Voila!

Answer (score 0):

I experienced the same problem, however if you switch to a different indenter in the pull down menu at the top of the ui(just below the text "Indenter Settings" and use a different indenter(i am using Uncrustify(C, C++, C#, Objective-C) it functions.  I suspect it has to do with the fact that all the indenters may not be bundled with the download BUT uncrustify is.  Most of the ones I tried have this issue, but the only one I care about is uncrustify.